# Do downvotes still cost reputation when the voter does not have the privilege?

Tags: support, downvotes

I cannot publicly down vote, however the site still accepts my feedback. Does this mean it is docking the post author rep or just working out whether the person should get a question ban or something?

Comment: Did you watch it go down?

Comment: When i refreshed the page i don't think i went down no but I thought it may take time to change.

Comment: @Dan13_ No, they don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course not.

You only lose rep when you successfully downvote an answer. If you are not a user or don't have the privilege to downvote, the vote will not count and you will keep all of your rep. Each site will gladly take your feedback into their statistics but the feedback will never become a vote unless you have the privilege to do so.

Comment: .. which are: [Vote up: at 15](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), [vote down: at 125](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).